# .Net format string to show In thousands, but also include comma separator

Tags: .net, format-string

I haven't seen an example of combining these 2 concepts.

1. Use "#,##0" to display a number with comma separators (e.g. 1832567 shows as 1,832,567)
2. Use "0," Format string to display a number in terms of thousands (e.g. 1832567 shows as 1833)

What if I want to show that same number in thousands And with comma separators (e.g. 1,833) ?

I'm sure there's ways to do it using formulas/calculations.  But I'd like to know if there's a direct way with a format string ?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure to have understood well, but _"#,##0,"_ seems to be doing what you have requested

Comment: @Steve `#,##0` shows `1,832,567` for the input. He wants to show `1,833`.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn with an ending comma, https://dotnetfiddle.net/leoOnc

Comment: @Steve nice. You should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This format will do what you have requested

```
"#,##0,"
```

as in

```
Console.WriteLine(1832567.ToString("#,##0,"));
```

You can see an example at https://dotnetfiddle.net/leoOnc

This seems to be described here at Custom Numeric Format Strings in the section dedicated to the [The "," custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#SpecifierTh) where they talk about how the comma could be used for both

> Group separator: If one or more commas are specified between two digit
> placeholders (0 or #) that format the integral digits of a number, a
> group separator character is inserted between each number group in the
> integral part of the output.
> ...
> Number scaling specifier: If one or more commas are specified
> immediately to the left of the explicit or implicit decimal point, the
> number to be formatted is divided by 1000 for each comma. For example,
> if the string "0,," is used to format the number 100 million, the
> output is "100".

Comment: That's it, thanks Steve!  I had gone to that document link, but hadn't read the details on custom specifiers.  Gotta read more carefully ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can divide by 1000.0 and the first format string will remove the extra characters:

```
int foo = 1832567;
Console.WriteLine( (foo/1000.0).ToString("#,##0"));
```

But that fails the "within a format string" part of the request. Maybe this can still qualify as part of an interpolated string, since we can fit everything between the curly braces:

```
int foo = 1832567;
Console.WriteLine($"{foo/1000.0:#,##0}");
```

Note the `.0` to avoid integer division, which would truncate rather than round the result.

Comment: Thanks, Joel.  Yes, I'd like to see if there's a way to do it with just the format. Looks like there isn't, so I'll have to do the calc. This is for an SSRS report, so it's much easier to apply one format to all the cells, rather than have to define an expression for each cell (even if the expression is the same construct for all fields).